# Running HtmlUnit in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to run HtmlUnit using Selenium WebDriver in C#.

When I run the following code (which as I understand it should start the HtmlUnit webdriver):

```
var caps = DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit();
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(caps);
```

I get the exception:

> Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:4444

As far as I'm concerned I need to have the HtmlUnit server running.
If anyone could help me out then I'd greatly appreciate it for sure!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Your command tries to connect to a Selenium node and doesn't start it.

Comment: please get more into detail.